# Data target not appending through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, addclass

Having trouble getting a data-target to append to a  tag. When I inspect the element the class shows up and href, but no `data-guideline=""`.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
var guideDelete = $('<a>').attr("href", "#").addClass('delete-asset').data("guidelineid", data.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be works too but try this:

```
var guideDelete = $('').attr("href", "#").addClass('delete-asset').attr("data-guidelineid", data.id);
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/58d6mzu4/)**

Answer (score 0):

@Moshtaf said its correct, But make habit of giving Id or Class to Element. so you can directly point to that element. like If I am doing then I will do,

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="myCustom">Let Me Click</a>

var guideDelete = $('#myCustom').attr("href", "#").addClass('delete-asset').data("guideLineId", data.id);
```

Though If you '' tag is dynamically created, Just follow the same, No matter If you have an Ajax.

Hoe this works for you :)